# Unable to toggle class via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a set of `tr` tags in a `table` and some of them have a class of `collapsible-parent`.  When I click on an element in the row it calls this javascript method:

```
function toggle() {
    $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil(".collapsible-parent").toggleClass("open");
}
```

But none of the rows inbetween are having the `open` class added.  So the HTML is something like so:

```
<tr class="collapsible-parent">
    <td>
        <span onclick="toggle()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></span>
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr class="collapsible-parent">....</tr>
```

so if I trigger that method on the first `tr` shown, I'd want the second and third `tr` to have the `open` class added to them.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: That would do something different, right?  That would walk 'up' the tree until it found one and then just toggle that one.  I'm wanting to toll all the sibling `tr` until I find another one with `collapsible-parent`

Comment: If you are using jQuery, use event listeners instead of calling your functions from html attributes. You're calling it so that `this` inside of it is undefined. Weren't you getting any error, didn't you do any debugging?

Comment: No, there are no errors printed in the console when that runs.

Comment: OK, I switched to using a class on the `span` and an event listener like you suggested and now it's working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just now realised that you have fixed your problem, though I will keep the answer for future reference as it is a tricky bug.

The `onclick` event listener is not captured correctly by jQuery. I have managed to run this successfully by adding an `id` on the `span` element and then adding an `.on("click")` listener using jQuery.

**Add an id on the span element:**

```
<span id="btn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></span>
```

**and add a listener using jQuery:**

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil(".collapsible-parent").toggleClass("open");
});
```